# subscribe() return undefined without console in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

My Project is in Angular 5 and I have to store API response into Variable. When I placed console.log inside subscribe it returns json array but without `console.log()` `subscribe()` returns undefined.

#### My Code

```js
 export class GalleryComponent {
 private apiUrl = 'http://fullpath';
 private response: any;
 private data: any;
 private category: any;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   this.getCategory();
 }

 /*getCategory() {
  this.http.post(this.apiUrl, {}).subscribe(res => {
     console.log(this.response = res['result']['data']);
  });---------------------This returns JSON data from API successfully*/
 getCategory() {
   this.http.post(this.apiUrl, {}).subscribe(res => {
      this.response = res['result']['data'];
   });
   console.log(this.response);//------This returns undefined
   }
 }
```

I am new in Angular.  How could I resolve this.

Comment: `console.log(this.response)` is called **before** `this.response = res['result']['data']`. This is because subscribe body will be called after getting response for your request. If you want to log response, simply put your log line **into** subscribe body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`http` calls are `asynchronous`, You need to write `console.log` in subscribe in order to print `response`.

```
getCategory() {
   this.http.post(this.apiUrl, {}).subscribe(res => {
     this.response = res['result']['data'];
     console.log(this.response);//<------This Will Work
    });
}
```

Comment: Can I make ngFor after this?

Comment: Yes, Of course. but then `this.response` needs to be array.

Comment: can you place code how to use NgFor with this. I shall be very thank full for you

Comment: `this.response` needs to be array, is it?

Comment: I will try. Thank you so much sir

Comment: Can you provide fully code that how to use this for NgFor.

Comment: Sure. can you show me what's data in `res['result']['data']`?

Comment: res['result']['data'] returns  {[id:2,category_name:"campus"]}

Comment: Use it like  : `<div *ngIf="response">
  <div *ngFor="let item of response">
   {{item.id}} -- {{item.category_name}}
  </div>
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

The way `subscribe` works is not affected by where you are placing your `console.log`. The reason you are experiencing this is due to the asynchronous nature of the operation the code is performing.

`getCategory()` is a function that wraps an http call, which is why you need to subscribe to the return value. Subscribing essentially means:

> Go and do whatever operation you need to do, when you are done, execute the stuff that's inside the subscribe block. But while I'm waiting, **go on with the rest of the code**

Hence, placing the `console.log` outside of the subscribe means that it will be executed before the asynchronous operation has finished.

Comment: Simply put the console log inside the subscribe

Answer (score 0):

http.post() function is asynchronous. You execute the post function and then you move on to the next statement. And only when the server responds, you enter the callback function that you passed to your http.post() function.
In the first case, you execute the console.log statement when you receive the response from the server.
In the second case, your console.log() will be executed right after the http call is performed, but before you get the response from the server.